# Cant access subdomain after multisite subdirectory install

Tags: multisite, nginx

I have seperated access url for accessing wp-admin. E.g:
For public url user can use : public.multisite.com
for Admin url access : admin.multisite.com
at condition public URL cant access wp-admin.

But after installing Multisite with subdirectory option, If i try access admin.example.com/wp-admin, always redirected to public.example.com.

Using Nginx + Laragon as WebServer

Below my wp-config settings

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'public.multisite.test' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name multisite.test *.multisite.test;
    root "/var/www/multisite";
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
      
    }
location ~* \.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
    # Enable SSL
    ssl_certificate "key.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "crt.key";
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```